# Compare a word with another line at same string in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have two lines in file. These lines' first word are same. I want to check the second word is same or not.
For example in the file which I called in the code :

**First line:** "A bcd acb acd sbd"
**Second line:** "A bcd asd asf adf"

I wrote this code:

```
        while ((command = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] array = amazing.split(" ");
            if (array[0].equals("A")) {

                System.out.println(amazing);
                Girl g1 = new Girl(array[1], array[2], array[3],
                        array[4], array[5], array[6]);  
            }  
         }
```

I want to compare `array[1]` of these two lines.
I hope i explained that clearly, thanks for your help.

Comment: This isn't that clear. Why can't you just read in the two lines, split them both, and use `lineOne[1].equals(lineTwo[2])`?

Comment: `Girl` constructor accepts `amazing` things :D

Comment: is your file contain only two line or more ?

Comment: where this `amazing` comes from ( amazing.split(" ") )

Comment: Make two arrays from the two lines and just compare their 2nd items `line1[1].equals(line2[1])` even better use `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun you are soo artistic!

Comment: Evan, the file has multiple lines, not just two. But honestly, i don't get your saying, could you explain that again? Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Yagnesh, has multiple lines. I read a file with BufferedReader and FileReader, and I called that amazing.

Comment: So you want to compare all lines one by one ?

Comment: I want to compare lines which first words are same. If first word is different, i check that later with other lines.

Comment: so you want to compare first line with second if not equal that first with third right ?

Comment: Yes, but right now, it's not my priority. I just want compare first line with second line. The other things are easy, if I explain that problem :)

Answer (score 0):

if in your file have only two lines than try this...

```
String st="";
String str[] = new String[2];
            int i=0;
            while((st=br.readLine())!=null){
                str[i++]=st;  // keep your text file line value in some variable
            }
       //now do what do you want
            String s[] = str[0].split(" ");
            String ss[] = str[1].split(" ");
            if(s.length<ss.length){
                for(int j=0;j<s.length;j++){
                    if(s[j].equals(ss[j])){
                        System.out.println("Equals word no."+(j+1));// its give you which word is same in both line
                    }
                }
            }else{
                for(int j=0;j<s.length;j++){
                    if(s[j].equals(ss[j])){
                        System.out.println("Equals word no."+s[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Output**

```
Equals word is.A
Equals word is.bcd
```

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you :

```
String line1,line2;
String[] ar_line1,ar_line2;
while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null && (line2 = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    ar_line1 = line1.split(" ");
    ar_line2 = line2.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<ar_line1.length;i++){
        if(ar_line1[i].equals(ar_line2[i])) {
                continue;
            }
            else{
                  System.out.println("Word are different at index : "+i);  
                  break;
            }
    }
}
```

Here i assume that both lien contains same number of words.If you want to compare ignoring case than use `ar_line1[i]..equalsIgnoreCase(ar_line2[i])`

1 I had read both line in starting of while loop
2 split both line with space
3 compare all words one by one
4 if words are equals than continue to next word if not than print message and break loop